# replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "") method not work

Tags: swift, string, character, backslash

I have string:

```
 let tokenStr = """
                          {"paymentData":{"data":"\(tokenApplePay.paymentData.data)","signature":"\(tokenApplePay.paymentData.signature)","header":{"publicKeyHash":"\(tokenApplePay.paymentData.header.publicKeyHash)","ephemeralPublicKey":"\(tokenApplePay.paymentData.header.ephemeralPublicKey)","transactionId":"\(tokenApplePay.paymentData.header.transactionId)"},"version":"\(tokenApplePay.paymentData.version)"},"paymentMethod":{"displayName":"\(tokenApplePay.paymentMethod.displayName)","network":"\(tokenApplePay.paymentMethod.network)","type":"\(tokenApplePay.paymentMethod.type)"},"transactionIdentifier":"\(tokenApplePay.transactionIdentifier)"}

                          """
```

in output I have string with backslashes "" :

```
 "{\"paymentData\":{\"data\":\"xxx\",\"signature\":\"xxx\",\"header\":{\"publicKeyHash\":\"xxx\",\"ephemeralPublicKey\":\"xxx\",\"transactionId\":\"xxx\"},\"version\":\"xxx\"},\"paymentMethod\":{\"displayName\":\"xxx\",\"network\":\"xxx\",\"type\":\"xxx\"},\"transactionIdentifier\":\"xxx\"}\n"
```

I tried to remove backslashes with:

```
let newStr = tokenStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
```

however, I get the same result, with "" and "\n" at the end. how to get rid of it?

I need to get the string without backslashes and without "\n"  in the end of the string.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Jatin I need to get the string without "\" backslashes

Comment: How you get that output?

Comment: @Cy-4AH I showed in the question. at the end I just do debugPrint(newStr)

Comment: There aren't there I guess. It's just how the value is shown in console. If possible, show them in a UILabel

Comment: I guess, you've done in console: `po tokenStr`, but if you do `po print(tokenStr)`, then won't appear. Also, if you do `print(tokenStr)` in code, it's the same. Not related, but you are trying to create JSON, so don't write the `String` manually, use `Codable` or `JSONSerialization`.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert it in `dictionary` and use it.

```
let str = "{\"paymentData\":{\"data\":\"xxx\",\"signature\":\"xxx\",\"header\":{\"publicKeyHash\":\"xxx\",\"ephemeralPublicKey\":\"xxx\",\"transactionId\":\"xxx\"},\"version\":\"xxx\"},\"paymentMethod\":{\"displayName\":\"xxx\",\"network\":\"xxx\",\"type\":\"xxx\"},\"transactionIdentifier\":\"xxx\"}\n"
        let data = str.data(using: .utf8)!
        do {
            if let dict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? [String:Any]
            {
               print(dict) // use the json here
            } else {
                print("bad json")
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
```

Comment: I tried. but it isn't work for me. 

this string still has backslashes.