# decoding dictionary to string without backslashes "\"

Tags: swift, string, dictionary, decode, backslash

I have string:

```
"{\"paymentData\":{\"data\":\"xxxxxxxx\",\"signature\":\"xxxxxxxxx\",\"header\":{\"publicKeyHash\":\"xxxxxx\",\"ephemeralPublicKey\":\"xxxxxxxx\"},\"version\":\"xxxxx\"},\"paymentMethod\":{\"displayName\":\"xxxxx\",\"network\":\"xxxxxx\",\"type\":\"xxxxx\"},\"transactionIdentifier\":\"xxxxxxx\"}\n"
```

but I need this line to not have "" backslashes.
I need something like this:

```
{"paymentData":{"data":"xxxxxxx","signature":"xxxxxx","header":{"publicKeyHash":"xxxxx","ephemeralPublicKey":"xxxxx","transactionId":"xxxxx"},"version":"xxxxx"},"paymentMethod":{"displayName":"xxxx","network":"xxxx","type":"xxxx"},"transactionIdentifier":"xxxxx"}
```

I saw that in similar questions here it was said that these backslashes will not be transmitted. but I need to use this line to make a hash in md5, and these backslashes are taken into account.
how to get rid of them?

I tried to do it:

```
let newStr = tokenStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
```

or it:

```
let string2 = string1.tokenStr.replacingOccurrences(#"\"#, with: "")
```

but unfortunately, those backslashes remain.

my string looks like this:

```
let tokenStr = """
                          {"paymentData":{"data":"\(tokenApplePay.paymentData.data)","signature":"\(tokenApplePay.paymentData.signature)","header":{"publicKeyHash":"\(tokenApplePay.paymentData.header.publicKeyHash)","ephemeralPublicKey":"\(tokenApplePay.paymentData.header.ephemeralPublicKey)","transactionId":"\(tokenApplePay.paymentData.header.transactionId)"},"version":"\(tokenApplePay.paymentData.version)"},"paymentMethod":{"displayName":"\(tokenApplePay.paymentMethod.displayName)","network":"\(tokenApplePay.paymentMethod.network)","type":"\(tokenApplePay.paymentMethod.type)"},"transactionIdentifier":"\(tokenApplePay.transactionIdentifier)"}
                          
                          """
```

if I convert this data to data, and decode to a model - then I get even more characters before each line

```
let tokenDict = ["paymentData" : paymentDataDict, "paymentMethod" : methodDict, "transactionIdentifier" : transactionIdentifierApplePay] as [String : Any]
            let tokenData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: tokenDict, options: [])
            let tokenApplePay = try jsonDecoder.decode(PaymentDataContainer.self, from: tokenData)
            debugPrint(tokenApplePay)
```

so how can I get a "clean" string without extra characters?

Comment: Did you actually try converting it to md5 hash? Please show a [mcve] of your code, that shows hashing the string you have produces a different hash than hashing a hard coded "clean" string. Also. use `print` instead of `debugPrint`, and print each of the string properties in the struct, separately. The extra backslashes are likely added because how you are printing.

Comment: *... these backslashes will not be transmitted*. That's true. The backslashes are virtual to be able to display double quotes in a string literal. Actually they don't exist (as well as the enclosing double quotes).

Comment: I still think (after a few questions), that the back slashes aren't there, they are just in console when printing. For the last one `tokenApplePay`, it doesn't make sense, you are relying on `description` of a (Codable) struct... It you use `print(tokenStr)` & `debugPrint(tokenStr)` you'll have different results...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "") method not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76253476/replacingoccurrencesof-with-method-not-work)

Comment: If you print the `String` to the standard-out, are there backslashes?

Answer (score -1):

```
    import Foundation

func prettyPrintJSON(_ jsonString: String) {
    guard let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) else {
        print("Invalid JSON string")
        return
    }
    
    do {
        let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
        
        if let prettyPrintedData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: [.prettyPrinted]),
           let prettyPrintedString = String(data: prettyPrintedData, encoding: .utf8) {
            print(prettyPrintedString)
        } else {
            print("Failed to pretty print JSON")
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error parsing JSON: \(error)")
    }
}

// Example usage
let jsonString = "{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":30,\"city\":\"New York\"}"
prettyPrintJSON(jsonString)
```

this will print:

```
{
  "name" : "John",
  "age" : 30,
  "city" : "New York"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use an extension on dictionary that returns string in a prettyprinted format. See the extension:

```swift
    extension Dictionary {
      func jsonFormat() -> String {
        var theString = ""
        if let theJSONData = try?  JSONSerialization.data(
            withJSONObject: self,
            options: .prettyPrinted
        ),
        let theJSONText = String(data: theJSONData,
                                    encoding: String.Encoding.ascii) {
            theString = theJSONText
        }
        return theString
      }
   }
```

to use it you just call .jsonFormat on your dictionary like this:

```swift
let tokenDict = ["paymentData" : paymentDataDict, "paymentMethod" : methodDict, "transactionIdentifier" : transactionIdentifierApplePay] as [String : Any]

let stringFormatDictionary = tokenDict.jsonFormat()
print(stringFormatDictionary)
```

prints:

```
{
  "transactionIdentifier" : "transactionIdentifierApplePay",
  "paymentData" : "paymentDataDict",
  "paymentMethod" : "methodDict"
}
```

which is a string